# Show different component when clicks the button in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have created the default layout and I hope that whenever I click each button, only certain parts of the layout will be changed by content component.
And I also use react router to control different pages.

Each button is pointing to a different URL.

```
<main
  className={clsx(classes.content, {
    [classes.contentShift]: open,
  })}
>
  <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
  {/* This part should change every button clicks!!! */}
</main>
```

I thought it can control in  but I don't have no idea for this.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={SignIn}>
    {/* <SignIn /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about">
    {/* <About /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    {/* <Users /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
  </Route>
    {/* <Home /> */}
</Switch>
```

My full live working codes are with codesandbox
[URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-create-react-app-express-4zs90?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark)

Comment: What is issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think your question is not more clear to be answered, But I guess your solution is to using `Link` or `NavLink` component of `react-router`. In fact, you should build your buttons just like below:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

~~
  <Link to="/about" className={classes.button} />
~~
```

But for a better answer you should explain more. I hope my answer help you dear.

Comment: @sangumee, I upvote you, but if you explain more, I can help you more.